# How can i print the variable i got from my server to client, in my html as a table?

Tags: javascript, html, json, server, client

Im setting up a server and client, and in the server i have a variable im sending over to my client. My client then needs to tell my html to print this variable as a table, but i cant find out how.

The server is up and running, and i recive the variable on my client. I have no problem printing the variable in my html when i click my button 'List of plants', but i dont know how to get it into a html table.

The message from the server, after calling a request from client, is used in this funtion:

```
function DisplayPlanter(planter = "") {
    console.log("Generating list");
    var Listen = planter;
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = Listen;

}
```

The server variable is:

```
var PlantList = "\
            {\"Plant\":  {\"Temp\": {\"Fugt\": [ \
            [\"Gulderod\", 14, 65], \
            [\"Løg\", 15, 40], \
            [\"Chili\", 23, 50], \
         ] } }";
```

This is the html button, calling requestList(), and this function is requesting the variable from the server, and that variable is printet in the id = "p3":

```html
<input type="button" onclick="requestList()" value="List of plants">
<p id = "p3"></p>
```

but right now it's just printing out:

```
{"Plant": {"Temp": {"Fugt": [ ["Gulderod", 14, 65], ["Løg", 15, 40], ["Chili", 23, 50], ] } }
```

This is from my browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/anJyb.jpg

I was wondering is there was an easy way to get this printet in a table?

I've found a code online, but i have trouble getting it to work. the code i found was this:

```
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var myBooks = [
            {
                "Book ID": "1",
                "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
                "Category": "Computers",
                "Price": "125.60"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "2",
                "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
                "Category": "Programming",
                "Price": "56.00"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "3",
                "Book Name": "Popular Science",
                "Category": "Science",
                "Price": "210.40"
            }
        ]

        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
```

Comment: This question spends a lot of time talking about what the server does and how that works when it's really not asking about how to get a value from a server. Your question should really just be "How to take an object and output it as a table?" and then you can just show what the object structure looks like.

Comment: your "server variable" missed closing curly bracket `}`. Is it a typo or real error?

Comment: There is No real error, its just When i try to use the exaple i showed, i just get the print: [Object Blob]